# How to fix the Lego Technic RC Stunt Racer (42095) set's turning drift?

Tags: technic, remote-control, vehicle, steering

I just finished the [Lego 42095 Stunt Racer](https://www.lego.com/en-de/product/remote-controlled-stunt-racer-42095) and noticed that there is a slight drift to the right when it drives forward. It works fine in reverse mode - reverses in a straight line.

Any suggestions, solutions please?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is that the motors are running at a slightly different RPM If both left and right motors run at exactly the same RPM they make us a straight line. PF L motors don't have rotation sensors to drive in straigth by default.